# Put a formula inside a cell using an automatic path

Tags: vba, excel

With VBA I'm trying to put automatic paths to my resources inside Excel cells.

 I've been trying to put a path from the directory where I launch my macro using:

```
ThisWorkbook.Path
```

This function works to delete a file as follows :

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fs.DeleteFile ThisWorkbook.Path & "\File.xlsx", force
```

But I'm experiencing some trouble when trying to use it inside the following line:

```
Range("E2").Formula = "='" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\[DJNDA.xls]Feuil1'!$I2"
```

Where I'm just wishing to obtain the value of a cell from a file in the same directory.
Right now the formula won't change if I move my file in another directory, that's why I want to use this kind of functions. I still use this kind of functions directly inside my cells:

```
='C:\path\to\file\[File.xls]Feuil1'!$I2
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the formula

```
= CELL("filename")
```

in your cell (after you have saved the workbook of course, so that a valid pathname exists for it).

Comment: I really need the formula Inside my cell so that I can extend the formula on a big range using `Selection.AutoFill`
I've only put the simplest formula by the way, Because it will be easier to understand, in the end I have to use `CONCATENATE` and some other excel functions.

Comment: @Calaom: Have you actually ***tried*** my suggestion? Or are you simply criticizing for the heck of it?

Comment: I don't actually see how I am suppose to use your suggestion, tried it in vba as following: `Range("E2").Formula = CELL("DJNDA.xls")`, it said sub or function undefined
Thank you if you could explain how you want me to use it

Comment: @Calaom: I thought you were trying to do: "put automatic paths to my resources inside Excel cells". That is what my suggestion is: a formula to "put inside a cell", not to attempt to use directly in VBA. Please, next time, READ WHAT I WROTE, not what you expected to see.

Comment: Tried your formula again and I found why it didn't worked at first..
I use the french version of excel so the formula CELL is named CELLULE...
Your solution will work with no doubt to do what I want.
Thanks a lot, sorry for the misunderstandings I had

Comment: ROFL. Glad to help - MY apologies for not even considering that there might be a real issue.